# How to use a template in a function whilst passing arguments by reference

Tags: c++

How do I use a template when passing an argument as a reference?

```
 template <typename T>

 void fun(T &A)
 {
      //code here
 }

 int main()
 {
      SomeElement A;
      fun(A);
      DifferentElement B;
      fun(B);
 }
```

Here is my error:

> error: use of undeclared identifier 'T'

Comment: Which compiler? Works fine for me with a dummy declaration for `SomeElement` and `DifferentElement` (tried with gcc, clang and vc++ on rextester.com)

Comment: Please [edit] your question to provide a [mcve].

Comment: I'm using Linux

Comment: Linux is not a compiler - you're probably using gcc. However current versions of gcc (or rather g++) will quite happily compile the above code. Please specify your actual compiler and version.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to specify template parameter values when you are calling `fun`:

```
SomeElement A;
fun<SomeElement>(A);
DifferentElement B;
fun<DifferentElement>(B);
```

Some compilers can deduce them automatically, but will give warnings.

Comment: Looks like OP is on an older compiler, which can't deduce types automatically.

Comment: Template argument deduction exists since before C++11 (fortunately)

Comment: @rerito my bad, I confused it with `template<auto non_type_parameter>`